# Me recorta los numeros en itextSharp de un codigo de barras

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy imprimiendo un `barcode` con `iTextsharp` pero en el `pdf` me lo recorta. Dejo las imágenes.

Tengo 18 dígitos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá me lo recorta a 13 dígitos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Alcides. Por favor, pon el codigo en formato de **texto**.

Comment: en esta url: http://eliasbobadilla.pe/blog/2017/11/05/generar-codigos-de-barra-128/ hay un codigo sencillo que devuelve un image codificado en code128 a partir de un string, el largo y ancho del código de barras es totalmente configurable . Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El standard [EAN13](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Article_Number), como su propio nombre indica, consta de 13 dígitos. No es posible meter mas, con lo que inteligentemente el iTextSharp trunca el dato que le pasas para que cumpla con la norma.

Si necesitas 18 caracteres, puedes probar con algún otro tipo de código de barras, como por ejemplo [Code-128](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128)